# LINQ Fluent Syntax - Deselecting Items in Array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with a Fluent LINQ query. I have a `Contributor` object with a `Product` array:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Role {get;set;}
    public string Publisher {get;set;}
}
public class Contributor
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Product[] ProductsContributedTo {get;set;}
}
```

I have a collection of `Contributor` and I want to filter the collections so that:

1. I only select `Contributor` records where a Author role record exists in the `Contributor.ProductsContributedTo` array.
2. Each contributor `Contributor.ProductsContributedTo` array should only include the Author roles.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
 var authors = contributors.SelectMany(people => people.ProductsContributedTo
                                  .Where(product => product.Role == "Author")
                                  .Select(c => people))
                                  .ToList();
```

So this is working whereby I'm selecting the correct Contributor records, but how do I filter the `Contributor.ProductsContributedTo` to only include the Author roles?

Here is a fiddle demonstrating that I have 3 Contributor records *Barry Collins*, *Maggie Fenwick* and *Sedgewick Foley*.  The above LINQ query is correctly selecting only Maggie Fenwick and Barry Collins, but how do I filter the `Contributor.ProductsContributedTo` array so that I only have their respective Author Product records?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hScdi4

**EDIT:**

I've made a slight change to the Fiddle, as each `Contributor` can Author multiple `Product` so I wanted to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much more complex than you thought:

```
List<Contributor> authors = contributors
    .Where(x => x.ProductsContributedTo.Any(y => y.Role == "Author"))
    .Select(x => new Contributor { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, ProductsContributedTo = x.ProductsContributedTo.Where(y => y.Role == "Author").ToArray() })
    .ToList();
```

You have to "clone" the `Contributor` to a new `Contributor` that has the filtered `ProductsContributedTo` list.

Note that I'm filtering twice for `Role == "Author"`, once for filtering the `Contributor`s, and once for filtering the `ProductsContributedTo` of the selected `Contributor`s`.

Other way, without repeating the check for `Role` is something like:

```
List<Contributor> authors = contributors
    .Select(x => new { Contributor = x, FilteredProducts = x.ProductsContributedTo.Where(y => y.Role == "Author").ToArray() })
    .Where(x => x.FilteredProducts.Length != 0)
    .Select(x => new Contributor { Id = x.Contributor.Id, Name = x.Contributor.Name, ProductsContributedTo = x.FilteredProducts })
    .ToList();
```

We "save" in an anonymous object the filtered `ProductsContributedTo` and then use this `FilteredProducts` to filter the `Contributor`s. This is more or less equivalent to using the `let` keyword with the keyword-based linq:

```
List<Contributor> authors = (from x in contributors
                             let filteredProducts = x.ProductsContributedTo.Where(y => y.Role == "Author").ToArray()
                             where filteredProducts.Length != 0
                             select new Contributor { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, ProductsContributedTo = filteredProducts }
                            ).ToList();
```

Note that often you can live well enough with an anonymous object containing separately the `Contributor` and its filtered `Product`s, while keeping inside the `Contributor` the full list of `Product`s:

```
List<Contributor> authors = contributors
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Contributor = x, 
        FilteredProducts = x.ProductsContributedTo.Where(y => y.Role == "Author").ToArray() 
    })
    .Where(x => x.FilteredProducts.Length != 0)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work, it first selects contributors with their author role products and then keeps only those with at least one product (to avoid iterating over the products collection multiple times):

```
contributors.Select(contributor => 
    new Contributor()
    {
        Id = contributor.Id,
        Name = contributor.Name,
        ProductsContributedTo = contributor.ProductsContributedTo.Where(
            product => (product.Role == "Author")).ToArray()
    }).
    Where(contributor => (contributor.ProductsContributedTo.Length > 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  The other solutions aren't using SelectMany.  Using just Select adds an extra layer which isn't necessary. :

```
            var authors = contributors.SelectMany(people => people.ProductsContributedTo
                                 .Where(product => product.Role == "Author").Select(product => new { Id = product.Id, publisher = product.Publisher })
                                 .Select(c => new { contributorId = people.Id, name = people.Name, productId = c.Id, publisher = c.publisher }))
                                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the contributor into valiables, you can remove the product which is having role other than "Author:

```
var authors = contributors.SelectMany(people => people.ProductsContributedTo
                              .Where(product => product.Role == "Author")
                              .Select(c => people))
                              .ToList();

authors.ForEach(people => people.ProductsContributedTo.RemoveAll(item => item.Role != "Author")));
```

And then process your variable.

Hope it helps.